# JSON-Patch 'remove' with empty path - What is the official, standard outcome?

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-patch

What is the standard outcome of the following 'remove' JSON Patch with an empty `""` path?

```
[{ "op": "remove", "path": ""}]
```

Should it clear the whole object, equal to assigning `{}`? In http://jsonpatch.com/ it says: *To point to the root of the document use an empty string for the pointer.* So I guess a 'remove' on the root removes the whole object, right?

I tried it with two different JSON Patch libraries with two different results:

- https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch: deletes the whole object
- https://github.com/gnieh/diffson: throws an JsResultException

What is the officially accepted, standard outcome of this? I checked in the RFC for the JSON Patch (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

RFC 6902 references this for further error handling: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.2

And to me, this part seems to fit the bill:

```
Resource not found:  Can be specified with a 404 (Not Found) status
  code when the client attempted to apply a patch document to a non-
  existent resource, but the patch document chosen cannot be applied
  to a non-existent resource.
```

Since you basically did not define any resource - not even `/` which would more clearly refer to the root / the entire object.

I guess the difference in the two libraries comes from that these two are usually considered identical:
`/my/resource`
`/my/resource/`

But usually the non-`/` path would be automatically 301 Redirected to the path that does have `/`. So I would personally go with the 404 response for `"path": ""`

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the RFC5789. I haven't looked in there yet. Although it's seems like RFC5789 is especially for when JSON Patch is used with the HTTP PATCH method.

Comment: Please refer to [RFC 6901](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901) to understand path property in question. Empty path define resource: the entire object, also "/" path is not equivalent of root. `{"": "me defined by '/' path!"}`
Removing root is not defined by RFC, but to make 'replace' operation functional 'remove' must remove whole object and return success.